# T4MVC Multiple types were found that match the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I have Home controller in main Controllers folder and in Controllers folder of some Area. As result I get an error telling ASP.NET MVC can not find out which of Home controllers to use:

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'home'. This
>   can happen if the route that services this request ('') does not
>   specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the
>   request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an
>   overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

I found a similar two years old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794163/t4mvc-and-duplicate-controller-names-in-different-areas). What is the current state of this feature? Should it work or may be I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, it's not only T4MVC problem, but MVC in general. Phil Haack [described it](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/12/ambiguous-controller-names.aspx) for MVC2, there wasn't much changes since then, afaik.

Btw, the error contains an exact suggestion what to do, did you follow it?

Comment: I know about ASP.NET MVC problem but T4MVC has a possibility to specify namespace by itself (al least theoretically). I wanted to know whether there were some improvements since the post I have references in the question

Comment: @Ldsa -> You have to specify the namespace for your routes in your route registration (that is by default in the global.asax), something T4MVC does not change.